# Why can't I pass a string as a parameter in a Javascript function?

Tags: php, javascript, function, arguments

I have the following code in php:

```
<?php
$apples = 123123;
echo "<td>
         <input type='button' onclick='confirmation($apples)' value='ac/in'>
      </td>";

echo('<script type="text/javascript">
           function confirmation(test) {
              var answer = confirm("Are you sure?")
              if (answer){
                  alert(test);
                  $.get("/index.php?f=func_name_to_call", 
                  {name: "John", hobby: "Programming"}, function(data) {});
              }
           }
</script>');
?>
```

If $apples is a number then the parameter gets passed correctly; however when it is a string, the function confirmation() is broken. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you send a string, it must be treated like so. Quote it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want it to pass argument as string use the below edited code

```
echo "<td><input type='button' onclick='confirmation(\"$apples\")' value='ac/in'></td>";
```

Just use `\` for escaping the double quotes,and it will be considered as a string.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `json_encode($apples)`. It will quote the variable for you if it is a string. As well as let you pass more complicated data structures (such as an associative array) into javascript.

Comment: It will also escape the string for you as well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you have to use escape character \"  \" in calling confirmation function because you pass integer in a integer type parameter which is without double quotes.therefore it converts the string into integer...

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$apples = 123123;
?>
<td>
    <input type='button' onclick='confirmation(<?php echo $apples?>)' value='ac/in'>
</td>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmation(test) {
        var answer = confirm("Are you sure?")
        if (answer){
            alert(test);
            $.get("/index.php?f=func_name_to_call", 
            {name: "John", hobby: "Programming"}, function(data) {});
        }
    }
</script>
```

you'll run into the trouble of converting all those `'` into `"` since your echoing them by `php`, just an advice dont `echo` them, use the `html` markup and just escape your `php`